# Как сохранить состояние запроса при пагинации

Tags: php, laravel

Столкнулся с проблемой после добавления пагинации. Есть фильтрация товаров:

```
$products = $category->products(); // получаю список товаров

// Собственно сама филтрация
if ($request->has('filter')) {
    foreach ($request->filter as $key => $filter) {
        $products->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($key, $filter) {
            // array_keys($filter) - берем только ключи из массива,
            // потому что значения всегда `1`. Не отмеченных checkbox тут нет.
            $query->whereIn('value_id', array_keys($filter))->where('attribute_id', (int) $key);
        });
    }
}
// конечный результат фильтрации разбивается на страницы
    $products = $products->paginate(10);
```

форма отправки фильтра на сервер:

```
        <form action="{{route('category.show', $category)}}">
            @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ $attribute->title }}</label>
                    @foreach($values as $value)
                        @if($attribute->id==$value->attribute_id)
                            <div style="" >
                                <br>
                                <input name="filter[{{$attribute->id}}][{{ $value->id }}]" type="checkbox" value="1"
                                        {{ empty(request()->filter[$attribute->id][$value->id]) ? '' : 'checked'   }} />
                                {{ $value->value }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                @endforeach

            <br>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Фильтровать</button>
        </form>
```

Таким образом рендерятся ссылки на странице:

```
{{$products->appends([request()->filter])->links() }}
```

После фильтрации URL ссылок на страницы формируется неправильно. 
После фильтрации в строке запроса URL такой: 
`category/1?filter%5B1%5D%5B37%5D=1&filter%5B1%5D%5B38%5D=1`
Но при формировании ссылок на страницы их URL формируется так, что filter меняется на 0 
`category/1?0%5B37%5D=1&0%5B38%5D=1&page=2`

Собственно вопрос: как правильно поместить результат фильтрации в пагинацию laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким способом `{{ $products->appends($_GET)->links() }}.`

Answer (score 0):

В методе контроллера, после пагинации добавляются нужные вам атрибуты фильтра:

```
// конечный результат фильтрации разбивается на страницы
$products = $products->paginate(10)->appends(request()->only('filter'));
```

Не забывайте о валидации данных.

Answer (score -1):

Так будет правильнее    `{{ $products->appends(request()->input())->links() }}`